# C++ ofstream, printing without CRLF

Tags: c++, linux, ofstream, carriage-return, wine

I have a C++ code I am running in Linux with wine. I think this is actually part of the problem.

Usually, when I do something like this in a native Linux C++ program:

```
ofstream fout;
fout.open("myfile.txt")
fout<<"blah blah"<<endl;
fout<<"blah blah 2"<<endl;
fout.close;
```

The file is standard ASCII text. However, in the code I an running under wine, myfile.txt is now ASCII text with CRLF line terminators.

This is a problem because if I want to read the file using a native Linux C++ code running on the same machine, the CRLF line terminators really mess up a lot of the file handling and parsing.

Is there a way to get the code running under wine to output files without CRLF line terminators and in a fashion that I can read it using the native Linux C++ code on the same machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could open the file in `ios::binary` mode. This doesn't, strictly speaking, mean that it's a binary file [any more than any other file is "text", since all files are binary]. Binary in this context just means "don't muck about with the stuff inside the file by interpreting characters as special, add or remove any characters, etc.

Or when you copy the file to Linux, use `dos2unix myfile.txt` to convert it from "dos" (and Windows) format to "unix" style text file.